# Failed to try to reset user password

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I tried to reset the password's user, but even though the user exists in the database I keep getting this error message: "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier or the user might be deleted"

Here is my code the OnComplete method is where I started getting this issue:

```
    @Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    String Mail=snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue(String.class);
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        num.setError(null);
        String sys_Email = snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue(String.class);
        if (sys_Email.equals(mail)) {
            Email.setError(null);
            String mail = snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue(String.class);
            mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(Email.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(forget_password.this, "check your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(forget_password.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert `Mail` `sys_Email` and `mail` variables **from this**:

```java
String Mail=snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue(String.class);
String sys_Email = snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue(String.class);
String mail = snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue(String.class);
```

**To this:**

```java
String Mail=snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue.toString();
String sys_Email = snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue.toString();
String mail = snapshot.child(numero).child("mail").getValue.toString();
```